# C# Making a gmail app that interacts with a users gmail account. I have to make a class level variable for gmailPassword and gmailAddress

Tags: c#

I have to make a class level variable for `gmailPassword` and `gmailAddress` and to see if they're logged in before you let them check messages or send mail. I have tried to work it out but cant seem to figure it out.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int userSelection;
    do
    {
        userSelection = Menu();

        if (userSelection == 2)
        {
            loggingOn();
        }

        else if (userSelection == 2)
        {
            getMail();
        }

        else if (userSelection == 4)
        {
            sendMail();
        }

    }
    while (userSelection != 4);
}


public static int Menu()
{
    if (loggedIn())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("__________Menu__________");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Close the application");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Enter your credentials");
        Console.WriteLine("3) Check for messages ");
        Console.WriteLine("4) Send a message");
        Console.WriteLine("________________________");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("____________Menu____________");
        Console.WriteLine("1) Close the application");
        Console.WriteLine("2) Enter your Credentials");
        Console.WriteLine("____________________________");
        Console.WriteLine("what would like to do?");
    }
    return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

}

public static bool loggedIn()
{

    if (gmailAddress == "" || gmailPassword == "")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public static void loggingOn()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your gmail address: ");
    gmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your gmail password");
    gmailPassword = Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void getMail()
{
    string[] messages = Gmail.getMail(gmailAddress, gmailPassword);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("_____Messages_____");
    for (int i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(messages[i]);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("_____________");
}

static void sendMail()
{
    Console.WriteLine("To address :");
    string toAddress = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Subject :");
    string subject = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Message :");
    string messageBody = Console.ReadLine();
    Gmail.sendMail(gmailAddress, gmailPassword, toAddress, subject, messageBody);
    Console.WriteLine("message sent");
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: cs0103 Doesnot exist in current context

Comment: You're asking about class level variables in a program where you have neglected to show any classes or fields. "I can't figure it out" is not a question; show your actual work, and then *ask a question*. Is your question "what is a field"?

Comment: Actual work? The code is there?

Comment: I believe gmail supports oauth2 as an authentication method.  Harder to implement, but still recommended over username/password credentialing, since it allows you to deauthenticate apps without changing your gmail password.  It also prevents your app's credentials from being used to permanently hijack your account.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a variable `IsAuthorized` of type `bool`

```
public static bool IsAuthorized {get;set;}
```

what this will do is set its value to `true` when user is logged in successfully

```
public static bool loggedIn()
{

    if (gmailAddress == "" || gmailPassword == "")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        IsAuthorized = true;
        return true;
    }
}
```

and you will do a check in SendMail like

```
static void sendMail()
{
   if(IsAuthorized)
   { 
    Console.WriteLine("To address :");
    string toAddress = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Subject :");
    string subject = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Message :");
    string messageBody = Console.ReadLine();
    Gmail.sendMail(gmailAddress, gmailPassword, toAddress, subject, messageBody);
    Console.WriteLine("message sent");

    }
      else
    {
               loggingOn();

    }
 }
```

it will check if used is not `loggedin` before it will go to `loggingOn()`; else it will send email. You can do this in other methods too.